# NSURL returning nil

Tags: ios, nsurl

I dont know why but when I am calling the following URL
it gives me BAD REQUEST - INVALID URL, although this URL is working fine on safari browser and other browsers as well

```
http://www.ysl.com/wx/shop-product/women/top-handles#{"ytosQuery":"true","department":"handbags_tophandle_w","gender":"D","brand":"","macro":"","micro":"","season":"A,P,E","color":"","size":"","site":"","section":"","sortRule":"","yurirulename":"searchwithdepartment","microcolor":"","agerange":"","macroMarchio":"","page":"2","productsPerPage":"50","modelnames":"","look":"","washtype":"","fabric":"","prints":"","suggestion":"false","suggestionValue":"","material":"","occasion":"","weight":"","gal
```

I am using following code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[payload stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]];

NSString* webStringURL = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

webStringURL = [str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *payload = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
```

Any Help Guys? What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `{` isn't legal in a URL.  In fact is that JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` on the hole URL, but just on the GET parameters.

Now `http://` will also be escaped, thus becoming `http%3A%2F%2F` which is not valid as an URL.

Comment: if you see, I am also addingpercentescape again in the whole URL.

Comment: You should not, on the parameters should be escaped.

Comment: You shouldn't be using either of those methods at all.  The first one removes escape sequences (but there aren't any), and the second one tries to add them back everywhere.  The right way to encode URL data is described at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html on Apple's developer website.  You'll also need to (__bridge CFStringRef) your NSStrings and (__bridge_transfer NSString *) them on the way back for ARC.